How to make the first text item in the row grow in width up to 50%
It needs to make a row in the column, the row should have two text items, the second should right align the first text item.
And when the first text has longer text content, it should grow up to a max width then wrap the text content. The second text item should have a max width as well. But it does not work using the code snippet below.

And if adding the ".weight(1f)" to the first text item's modifier, it does not respect the firt text item's maxWidth:

How to make the first text item has a max width 50% of the screen, and the second text item flow next to the first text item?
The following implementation does not work if the first text item has long text content
@Composable
fun RowTest(firstText: String, secondText: String) {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            // First Text: Wraps content if too long
            Text(
                text = firstText,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                modifier = Modifier
                    //.weight(1f) //<=== does not work, the max = 360 is not respected.
                    .padding(end = 6.dp)
                    .widthIn(max = 360.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )

            // Second Text: Aligns to the end of the available space
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides Color.Cyan) {
                Text(
                    text = secondText,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                        .widthIn(min = 100.dp, max=260.dp)
                        .background(Color.DarkGray)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun RowTestPreView() {
    RowTest("firstText: ertergegergergerg erwewewe ===  eee 888 String", "secondText:  wewef w er we r we reee e eee 888 String")
}


Try using requiredWidthIn instead of widthIn for both texts.

@Abdo21, it does not work, the first Text run over the second Text.

try running it on a real device since the preview might not work correctly sometimes. I tested it on my device, and it respects the constraints you provided: the first text with maxWidth = 360.dp, and the second with minWidth = 100.dp and maxWidth = 260.dp.

Keep in mind that when using required*(), it ignores parent constraints. For example, in your case, the first text takes the maximum width you specified since there's enough text, and the second text does the same. If their sum width exceeds the screen size, the second text will be partially visible. This happened on my device with the text you. provided.

Try using the below implementation and change it to your own use if it doesn't match your requirements.
Layout(content = {
    Text(text = "Your text here", Modifier.layoutId("text 1"))
    Text(text = "Your text here", Modifier.layoutId("text 2"))
}, measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
    val startTextPlaceable = measurables.first { it.layoutId == "text 1" }.measure(
        constraints.copy(maxWidth = 360)    //your value
    )

    val endTextPlaceable = measurables.first { it.layoutId == "text 2" }.measure(
        constraints
    )

    val height = startTextPlaceable.height.coerceAtLeast(endTextPlaceable.height)

    layout(constraints.maxWidth, height) {
        endTextPlaceable.placeRelative(startTextPlaceable.width, 0)
        startTextPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
    }
})


Thanks @Ajay. Learned something to use the constrain with composable. The snippet achieves that the second Text flow by right side of the first Text and the first Text respects its max width. Need to try how to make the second Text takes over all of the right side remaining available space and wrap if needed.

I guess you can set that in the constraints you provide for the second text itself. Just set your max width of second text according to the use case and you are good to go.
